# How to use HTTP Interceptor to retrieve HTTP Header values

Tags: angular, request, http-headers, response

i'm trying to utilize an HTTP Interceptor to retrieve HTTP Header value that will be used for authentication purposes. Our application sits behind a F5 and access policy rules force the user to provide a client sll certificate, and then uses iRules to inject the cert (whole cert, and cert-subject).
The idea is to retrieve the cert and make a service call to use it for authentication purposes on the loading of the app, and then create the authorize token.
the problem i'm facing is i'm unable to implement the interceptor

i have create the AppHttpInterceptor in the root app, and registered it in app.module.ts
when running the application, nothing is being logged out in the browser console

```
import {Injectable} from "@angular/core";
import {HttpEvent, HttpHandler, HttpInterceptor,HttpRequest, HttpResponse} from "@angular/common/http";
import {Observable, pipe} from "rxjs";

@Injectable()
export class AppHttpInterceptor implements HttpInterceptor {

    constructor() {
    }

    intercept(request: HttpRequest<any>, next: HttpHandler): Observable<HttpEvent<any>> {
      const headerKeys = request.headers.keys();
      console.log('Testing Interceptor');
      console.log(request);
      return next.handle(request);
    }
  }
```

and then the app.module.ts

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { AppRoutingModule } from './app-routing.module';
import { BrowserAnimationsModule } from '@angular/platform-browser/animations';

import { AppComponent } from './app.component';
import { MenuBarModule, AuthBannerModule } from './components';
import { AdminPageModule } from './pages';
import { FormsModule, ReactiveFormsModule } from '@angular/forms';
import { HttpClientModule, HTTP_INTERCEPTORS } from "@angular/common/http";
import { AppHttpInterceptor } from './AppHttpInterceptor';

@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent,
  ],
  imports: [
    AdminPageModule,
    AppRoutingModule,
    AuthBannerModule,
    BrowserModule,
    MenuBarModule,
    BrowserAnimationsModule,
    FormsModule,
    ReactiveFormsModule,
    HttpClientModule
  ],
  providers: [
    {provide: HTTP_INTERCEPTORS, useClass: AppHttpInterceptor, multi: true }
  ],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }
```